# Spring MVC validation annotations not displaying error messages

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to spring framework. Currently, I am doing spring validations using annotations.

So look at my DAO Class:

```
public class Spitter {
    private Long id;

    @NotNull(message = "Username cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 10, max = 14, message = "Username must be between 10 and 14 characters long")
    private String username;
SETTERS AND GETTERS }
```

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/spitters")
public class SpitterController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createSpitterProfile(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("spitter", new Spitter());
        return "spitters/edit";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/createAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addSpitterFromForm(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("spitter")Spitter spitter, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "spitters/edit";
        } else {
            //    spitterService.addSpitter(spitter);
            return "redirect:/home";
        }
    }
}
```

And JSP file:

```
<%--suppress XmlDuplicatedId --%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Spitter</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Create free Spitter account</h2>
<sf:form action="/spitters/edit/createAccount"
         method="post" commandName="spitter">
  <table class="formtable">
    <tr>
      <td class="label">User Name</td>
      <td><sf:input class="control" name="username" path="username"
                    type="text"></sf:input></br>
        <sf:errors path="username"></sf:errors></td>
    </tr>
      <td class="label"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</sf:form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, Spitter Controller can receive data from jsp form. But constraints(@NotNull and @Size) added in DAO Class don't work and I don't know why.

Comment: Please be more spceific about the non-working constraints. An example would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please be more spceific about the non-working constraints. An example
>   would help

Maybe your bean data is valid and username is just empty string. I think you use Hibernate Validator, if so try to add @NotEmpty constraint to username field

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to register bean `MethodValidationPostProcessor`. See [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#validation-beanvalidation-spring-method)